# What is complexity measured against? (bits, number of elements, ...)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I've read that the naive approach to testing primality has exponential complexity because you judge the algorithm by the size of its input.  Mysteriously, people insist that when discussing primality of an integer, the appropriate measure of the size of the input is the number of bits (not n, the integer itself).

However, when discussing an algorithm like Floyd's, the complexity is often stated in terms of the number of nodes without regard to the number of bits required to store those nodes.

I'm not trying to make an argument here.  I honestly don't understand the reasoning.  Please explain.  Thanks.

Comment: Probably better asked on [cs.se]

Comment: If I'm off topic, then I won't be offended.  But I believe real programmers are quite adequate to explain this.

Comment: It's a bit hard to discuss without knowing what algorithm you are talking about exactly

Comment: This isn't off topic for sure but you might get a more appropriate answer given your background. Algorithms are, or rather should be, judged based on context. Otherwise, the measurement is useless.

Comment: The reason why I didn't specify a particular algorithm is that complexity doesn't mean anything unless you have some unified approach that applies to any algorithm in question.

Comment: I'm sure that real programmers are quite adequate to explain how to make a cup of tea, but [so] is not the best place to ask. I merely suggested that [cs.se] might be a _better_ place

Comment: @AdamCross in my experience is like this "wait I cannot answer that question ... it **must** be OT!  - just ignore those ;)

Comment: @AdamCross the problem here is that you have to think about the basic operations like multiplikation/division here too - and those depend on the number of bits (for larger numbers at least)

Comment: Ooow, don't go there. You got as many ups as downs *at this point* but comments like that encourage the worst in people.  2 up and 2 down says to me you have nearly a majority; not bad.

Comment: Fair point.  It might matter if SO reputation meant anything.  I am, however, grateful to those of you who know much and share what you know.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally speaking, the complexity is measured against the **size of input**.

In case of numbers, the size of input is log of this number (because it is a binary representation of it), in case of graphs, all edges and vertices must be represented somehow in the input, so the size of the input is linear in `|V|` and `|E|`.

For example, naive primality test that runs in linear time of the number itself, is called *pseudo-polynomial*. It is polynomial in the number, but it is NOT polynomial in the size of the input, which is `log(n)`, and it is in fact exponential in the size of the input.

---

As a side note, it does not matter if you use the size of the input in bits, bytes, or any other CONSTANT factor for this matter, because it will be discarded anyway later on when computing the asymptotical notation as constants.

Comment: I think you may have answered my question, but I want to think on it for a bit.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Also, I'd add something about how a pseudo-polynomial algorithm may not be exponential if it runs in a machine with a unary number system.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that when discussing algorithms we keep in the back of our mind a hardware that is able to perform operations on the data used in O(1) time. When being strict or when considering data which is not able to fit into the processors register then taking the number of bits in account becomes important.

Answer (score 0):

Although the size of input is measured in the number of bits, in many cases we can use a shortcut that lets us divide out a constant number of bits. This constant factor is embedded in the representation that we choose for our data structure.

When discussing graph algorithms, we assume that each vertex and each edge has a fixed cost of representation in terms of the number of bits, which does not depend of the number of vertices and edges. This assumption requires that weights associated with vertices and edges have fixed size in terms of the number of bits (i.e. all integers, all floats, etc.)

With this assumption in place, adjacency list representation has fixed size per edge or vertex, because we need one pointer per edge and one pointer per vertex, in addition to the weights, which we presume to be of constant size as well.

Same goes for adjacency matrix representation, because we need W(E<sup>2</sup> + V) bits for the matrix, where W is the number of bits required to store the weight.

In rare situations when weights themselves are dependent on the number of vertices or edges the assumption of fixed weight no longer holds, so we must go back to counting the number of bits.

Comment: This answer definitely adds to the previous answers.  I think maybe the answer to my question is here already, but I want to think on it a bit and make sure I understand.  Thanks for your input.